# Is it possible to extract private key from a keystore?

Tags: openssl, certificate, keytool, csr

I'm new to digital certificates and currently stuck with below problem. 
I created a Keystore & CSR with keytool and got the certificate downloaded using CSR.

Here are the steps I am supposed to follow as per the instructions:

1. Create an OpenSSL private key
2. Create a CSR using Private Key
3. Get CRT generated
4. Use Key + CRT to generate the PFX file
5. Create Keystore with PFX
6. Rename jks to P12
7. Import Entrust intermediate & root certificates into the trust store
8. Create a pem certificate from p12
9. Export the private key from p12
10. Convert private key to a plain key
11. Use cert.pem & plainkey.pem for authentication

But, I used keytool to create a keystore and CSR instead of OpenSSL and got the CRT generated. I am stuck at step 4 - 4. Use Key + CRT to generate the PFX file as I have the keystore but not the private key.

How should I move forward?

Answer (score 0):

> I have the keystore but not the private key

You have the private key from step 1, haven't you? Use this one.